# Tooltip like Dialog Box in Cakephp - Similar to stackoverflow boxes

Tags: jquery, html, cakephp, dialog, tooltip

I am working onn a project based on the cakephp framework.  On my index page if  you add or edit an item, currently the cakephp Session->setFlash code places the text right above the page title.  It will say "itemName has been successfully changed" or "itemName has been successfully added".  (itemName is the name of the object they added/edited to the database table).

Currently, when adding or editing items, a dialog box pops up with input fields for information.  All of that stuff works, i just want to add a little more functionality.  What I want to do is, when valid data is entered and they click submit, instead of having the "successfully ..." text appear in the page (due to $this->Session->setflash()), I want a small popup box, similar to a dialog box, with a message it in that automatically disappears after a few seconds or can it can be manually closed.

I would like something that works similar to the dialog boxes stackoverflow uses, for example when you click on the upvote arrow and the message box appears saying you dont have enough reputation to upvote.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

PS - I dont know what to call these boxes, they are a mix between dialog boxes and tooltips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For things like that you need to use jQuery that is triggered but an ajax call, either successful or not.

1. Setup AJAX for the FORM submission
2. Use jQuery to handle AJAX responses with a POPUP.

In terms of jQuery, there are several options out there:

1. http://www.jquerypopup.com/demo.php
2. http://www.shanestrong.com/jquery/popup/popup.htm
3. http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/

If you do a google search for jQuery Popup you will find many options.

In terms of help with the coding itself, if you post your code here, anyone in here should be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll be experimenting with these.

Comment: No problem. Let us know if you need anymore help and we will be glad to help out...